# "hour" counter won't reset, after the program is run again

Tags: c++, for-loop, counter, reset

I can't figure out how to reset the "hour" counter.

The program runs perfect on the 1st run, but when user enters another set of hours, hours start numbering between 110-117.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const float initialVolume = 130.00; 
const float decreaseRate = 0.13; 
int counter = 0;

int main()
{
int hours,i,j,k;
float remainingVolume, halfVolume, zeroVolume;

while (cout << "Enter hours to see how much caffeine "
     << "is left in your body, after you drank your coffee: " && cin >> hours)
{
cout << endl;
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(4);

remainingVolume = initialVolume;

for (i = 0; i < hours; i++)
{
    counter++;
    remainingVolume = remainingVolume - decreaseRate * remainingVolume;
    cout << "Hour " << setw(5) << counter << setw(15) << remainingVolume << "mg"<< endl;
}

for (j = 0, halfVolume = 130.00; halfVolume > 65.0000; j++)
{
    counter++;
    halfVolume = halfVolume - decreaseRate * halfVolume;
}

for (k = 0, zeroVolume = 130.00; zeroVolume > 0.0001; k++)
{
    counter++;
    zeroVolume = zeroVolume - decreaseRate * zeroVolume;
}

cout << "\n" << endl;
cout << "It will take " << j << " hours to get caffeine levels to 65mg. \n" << endl;
cout << "It will take " << k << " hours to get caffeine levels to 0mg. \n\n" << endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

output:

> Enter hours to see how much caffeine is left in your body, after you
>   drank your coffee: 4
>
> Hour     1       113.1000mg
>   Hour     2        98.3970mg
>   Hour     3        85.6054mg
>   Hour     4        74.4767mg
>
> Enter hours to see how much caffeine is left in your body, after you
>   drank your coffee: 3
>
> Hour   112       113.1000mg
>   Hour   113        98.3970mg
>   Hour   114        85.6054mg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are never resetting your `counter` value. You initialise it to 0 and then increase it in every loop. you need to reset it to 0 every time they enter a new number (ie in your while loop).

The best solution would be to have to counter variable as a local variable declared in the loop:

```
while (cout << "Enter hours to see how much caffeine "
     << "is left in your body, after you drank your coffee: " && cin >> hours)
{
int counter=0;
cout << endl;
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(4);

remainingVolume = initialVolume;

for (i = 0; i < hours; i++)
{
    counter++;
    remainingVolume = remainingVolume - decreaseRate * remainingVolume;
    cout << "Hour " << setw(5) << counter << setw(15) << remainingVolume << "mg"<< endl;
}

for (j = 0, halfVolume = 130.00; halfVolume > 65.0000; j++)
{
    counter++;
    halfVolume = halfVolume - decreaseRate * halfVolume;
}

for (k = 0, zeroVolume = 130.00; zeroVolume > 0.0001; k++)
{
    counter++;
    zeroVolume = zeroVolume - decreaseRate * zeroVolume;
}

cout << "\n" << endl;
cout << "It will take " << j << " hours to get caffeine levels to 65mg. \n" << endl;
cout << "It will take " << k << " hours to get caffeine levels to 0mg. \n\n" << endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Of course it was something so simple, and I couldn't figure it out. Thank you!!

Comment: you should step through the application in the debugger and monitor the values. Learning how to debug correctly is one of the most useful skills you can give yourself.

Comment: I was trying to figure out if I should add in another loop for the counter, in the end of the program. It didn't occur to me to put the counter at the beginning of the program.

I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the counter after you're done with your iteration:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const float initialVolume = 130.00; 
const float decreaseRate = 0.13; 
int counter = 0;

int main()
{
int hours,i,j,k;
float remainingVolume, halfVolume, zeroVolume;

while (cout << "Enter hours to see how much caffeine "
     << "is left in your body, after you drank your coffee: " && cin >> hours)
{
cout << endl;
cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(4);

remainingVolume = initialVolume;

for (i = 0; i < hours; i++)
{
    counter++;
    remainingVolume = remainingVolume - decreaseRate * remainingVolume;
    cout << "Hour " << setw(5) << counter << setw(15) << remainingVolume << "mg"<< endl;
}

for (j = 0, halfVolume = 130.00; halfVolume > 65.0000; j++)
{
    counter++;
    halfVolume = halfVolume - decreaseRate * halfVolume;
}

for (k = 0, zeroVolume = 130.00; zeroVolume > 0.0001; k++)
{
    counter++;
    zeroVolume = zeroVolume - decreaseRate * zeroVolume;
}

cout << "\n" << endl;
cout << "It will take " << j << " hours to get caffeine levels to 65mg. \n" << endl;
cout << "It will take " << k << " hours to get caffeine levels to 0mg. \n\n" << endl;

counter = 0; // <--
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: or better, use counter as a local variable